# Display annotaion in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to build a table with 12 months, a row with total project income per month, so in my `ListView` I'm [annotating](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#aggregating-annotations) my `price` like this

```
from django.db import connection

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProjectStatisticsList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

    truncate_month = connection.ops.date_trunc_sql("year", "month")
    total_price_per_month = Project.objects.extra({"month": truncate_month}).values("month").\
        annotate(sum_price=Sum("price")
```

I'm little confused on how to `for loop` over month in template and display `total_price_per_month` for each month?

Comment: What does your output look like ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a dict containing `total_price_per_month` from that method. In your template you can then just iterate over that and reference the values:

```
{% for data in total_price_per_month %}
    Month: {{ data.month }}
    Price: {{ data.sum_price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: yea, this is correct, I need to work on my annotation, the data is incomplete, I'm not returning anything